# Run abaqus inp file from python

Tags: python, python-3.x, abaqus

I am fairly new in crossing over abaqus and python. I want to run abaqus from python. I tried searching but didn't get much help. How do I do it ?

I tried this. I don't know if this even works and am I in the right path or no.

```
import abaqus
import abaqusConstants

myJob = mdb.JobFromInputFile(inputFileName="C:\Users\sel\Desktop\My work\Python Abaqus\Concrete Beam\Final\Job-1.inp", name="Firstjob", type=ANALYSIS, waitMinutes=15, numCpus=20, explicitPrecision=DOUBLE, nodalOutputPrecision=FULL, parallelizationMethodExplicit=DOMAIN, numDomains=20, multiprocessingMode=DEFAULT)
myJob.submit()
myJob.waitForCompletion()
```

And got this error:

File "", line 4
    myJob = mdb.JobFromInputFile(inputFileName="C:\Users\sel\Desktop\My work\Python Abaqus\Concrete Beam\Final\Job-1.inp", name="Firstjob", type=ANALYSIS, waitMinutes=15, numCpus=20, explicitPrecision=DOUBLE, nodalOutputPrecision=FULL, parallelizationMethodExplicit=DOMAIN, numDomains=20)
                                              ^

SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: what did you try? did you look at the [docs](http://dsk.ippt.pan.pl/docs/abaqus/v6.13/books/cmd/default.htm)?

Comment: @Nullman I have edited. please take a look

Comment: backslashes need escaping, or use a raw string: add the letter `r` in your input string like so `inputFileName = r"C:\Us....."`

Comment: @Nullman I did that and now I am getting this error " ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'abaqus' "

Comment: are you using the python that was supplied with abaqus or your own version?

Comment: python and abaqus 6.14-5 are seperately installed. How do I install the module?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210223/discussion-between-devinxxxd-and-nullman).